Unable to include header from catkin package
I'm building a ROS package my_ros_lib that builds a library, along with some general-purpose headers:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
project(my_ros_lib VERSION 1.0)

# ...

find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp std_msgs controller_manager controller_manager_msgs)

# ...

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
    CATKIN_DEPENDS controller_manager controller_manager_msgs gazebo_ros gazebo_msgs geometry_msgs std_msgs std_srvs dynamic_reconfigure tf2 tf2_geometry_msgs
    # DEPENDS ...
)

# ...

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# client library
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib.cpp)

# target header locations
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}>
                                                  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
                                                  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}>
                                                  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

which I want to use from other package my_ros_pkg:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)
project(my_ros_pkg VERSION 1.0)

# ...

find_package(catkin REQUIRED roscpp std_msgs my_ros_lib)

# ...

catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
    CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime my_ros_lib
    # DEPENDS ...
)

# ...

include_directories(
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp)

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/some_source.cpp
                                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/some_other_source.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}>
                                                  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
                                                  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}>
                                                  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/${PROJECT_NAME}>)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
    ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS}
)

However, those headers aren't being properly exported/installed, as I can't see them under devel/my_ros_lib/ and, when trying to include them from e.g. my_ros_pkg/src/some_source.cpp, I get No such file or directory.
I've tried declaring the headers as INTERFACE sources specifically:
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}/some_header.hpp
                                         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/${PROJECT_NAME}/some_other_header.hpp)

but catkin is unable to find my_ros_lib during compilation of my_ros_pkg: The library is neither a target nor built/installed properly likely related to this.
How do I solve this?
